# Consume data from other database motor from stored procedure in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, informix

I have a project in which you must develop services in Oracle OSB which will call a procedure stored in Oracle 12c. The issue is that I also need data from an Informix database to build those services.
The initial idea was to make a DBlink from Oracle to informix, but it is very expensive, because it needs licensing. I need alternatives to this problem.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Database Gateway and Generic Connectivity (DG4ODBC) Licensing Considerations (Doc ID 232482.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=232482.1)

> The Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC (DG4ODBC) is included in your
>   Oracle Database Server license without extra cost.
>
> ...
>
> While the
>   Database Gateway for ODBC (DG4ODBC) does not require an additional
>   license from Oracle, a third party ODBC driver is required, which may
>   require a purchase independent of Oracle.

Yes, Database Gateway for Informix requires the purchase of additional license.

No, Database Gateway for ODBC does not require the purchase of additional license.

All you need is a 3rd party ODBC driver which is compatible with Informix, then you can configure DG4ODBC to use that.

I have done this with IBM DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server before, it should work with Informix as well.